# What's wrong with my AES encryption function in C#? Why does it return zero length data?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

```
public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] data, string[] aes_key)
{
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    aes.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[0]);
    aes.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[1]);

    var encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    return ms.ToArray();
}

public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] data, string[] aes_key)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    aes.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[0]);
    aes.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[1]);

    var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Somewhere in code:

```
string key = "788b0adbcf8b9211282fe613b18630d2";
string iv = "7fbb16b806fcc24396653b3218552d39";
byte[] test_byte = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
byte[] enc_byte = AES_Encrypt(test_byte, new string[] { key, iv }); //getting zero array
byte[] dec_byte = AES_Decrypt(enc_byte, new string[] { key, iv });
```

Comment: You may need to close cs first to force it to flush before you copy it, I'm also not certain whether you need to seek to the beginning of the MS before the to array call

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. Now, at least, it looks like may work :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `using` blocks around your streams to ensure they are closed and flushed. Try this:

```
public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] data, string[] aes_key)
{
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    aes.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[0]);
    aes.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[1]);

    var encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

      return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] data, string[] aes_key)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    aes.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[0]);
    aes.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aes_key[1]);

    var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

      return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`using` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) with your [`CryptoStream`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx), it will flush and close so that it actually updates your `MemoryStream`s. The documentation for `CryptoStream` documents this behavior: you should always `Close` when you're done writing to it. Here's how that looks (very similar for encrypt and decrypt):

```
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
return ms.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call [FlushFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock.aspx) before converting the stream to array.